# how to create file download link to a file stored in MYSQL database with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink, download

I know I can just upload the file to a folder in my server, save the directory location to the MYSQL database, and create a download link based on that directory location but what happens when you store a file like a pdf or zip archive directly on the MYSQL database? How do you retrieve that data and create a file download link then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to set some content headers before outputting the data from your database, like:

```
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");
echo $data;
```

Full example at http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2000/09/15/php_mysql.html?page=3

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't store file data in your database, that's what the file system is for!

However to answer your question you would store the file contents in a `BLOB` field which contains the binary data, then to download throw the correct headers and echo the field value.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a php file like "download.php" that put the headers of that file type (and size) and the echo the contents of the file stored.